How to position HTML dialog element at bottom of page with full width?
I'm trying to position an HTML <dialog> element at the bottom of a page and I want it to stretch across the entire viewport width.
Here's the CSS I tried so far.
#dia {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: auto 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

It mostly works. It moves the dialog to the bottom left corner of the page.
However, the dialog doesn't reach the right side of the viewport.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b078wk6m/
Any ideas on why it's stopping short of the right edge? And how I can get it to reach the right edge for any screen width?

Some browsers automatically add styles to dialogs as u can see in the screenshot, 
You should overwrite the max-width and make it max-width: 100%; that should work!

there is  a default max-width applied to dialog.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  const dia = document.querySelector("#dia");
  
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    dia.showModal();
  });
  dia.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target === dia) {
        dia.close();
    }
  });
});
#dia {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: auto 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%; /* add this */
}
<dialog id="dia">
  <p>hello world!</p>
</dialog>

<button id="btn">
  toggle
</button>





Remove  this property as per your code
padding: 0;


Before :
#dia {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: auto 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

After :
#dia {
  border: 0;
  margin: auto 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}


Add max-wdith:

 #dia {
         padding: 0;
         border: 0;
         margin: auto 0 0 0;
         width: 100%;
         max-width: 100%
       }



why remove the padding? that does not change anything?
